# Checkbox not calling ngOnChanges

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this component:

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input type="checkbox" id="1" [checked]="ck">`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges  {
  @Input()
  ck=true;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    alert(2);
  }
}
```

If I change `ck=true` to `ck=false` the website reloads unchecked (and vice-versa). It let me think it's displaying correctly.

But the alert never called.

### Edit

Added the `@Input()` thing suggested in the comments.

Comment: That component has no `@Input`s, so what changes do you expect that method to get called on?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I neither have a `@Output` but its displaying anyway.

Comment: Why would that have anything to do with it? Maybe you should read https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks. Your code is working fine, the problem is your expectations are incorrect.

Comment: @jonrsharpe HTTP Error 503. They are using hooks? Hook-patterns are antipattern. I drop that angular thing.

Comment: Loads fine for me. And whatever, but maybe read the docs of the replacement you pick; guessing isn't often productive.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I will wait until tomorrow. Ill try to add this `@Input` thing.

Comment: ...and what difference did that make? Where are you loading this component; do you pass a value to that input? Do you *change* it?! Why are you *expecting* the alert to get called?

Comment: @jonrsharpe 1. I noticed no difference. 2. I am passing a initial value of `true` to the model of the input using the component's field `ck`. 3. I change the value of the checkbox by click the checkbox and let the check in the box disappear.

Comment: You're setting the initial value to true *locally*, but are you changing the bound input value? If you want the method to get called when you change the checkbox value then this isn't even close, you need to look at the forms handling. I'd strongly recommend running though e.g. https://angular.io/tutorial to get to grips with the basics.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The page does not tell anything about the version of angular. Id like to use angular version 2. Do I have to understand angular 1 before I start using angular 2 or is it version independ? The page does not inform about that let me think its for experienced angular experts only. I cant not differ angular 1 articles from angular 2 articles. And why is the answer to this simple question that hard? Answer 1: No, I expect to let angular do that automatically.

Comment: It's an explicitly introductory tutorial, so that's an extremely weird assumption to make. If you want to know about AngularJS vs. Angular then do a bit of research; I doubt you want 2.x specifically at this point. Frankly I see no point to discussing this further.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hm, you tell not clearly what you mean. 1. What are pointless to discuss, my question at SO or the difference between AngularJS and Angular? 2. As AngularJS means `JavaScript-based` (explaination from https://www.simplilearn.com/angularjs-vs-angular-2-vs-angular-4-differences-article ) and the code I posted is clearly TypeScript it can not be AngularJS! So the difference between AngularJS and Angular is obsoletely introduced by you right? Did I miss a point? 3. I like 2.x specifically at this point, why not? Please referr to the unique answers for systematical answering please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-OnChange is for events from outside of the component, for the "input" parameters.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-on-change-and-checkbox?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

if you want to trigger some methode, make change-method:

`<input type="checkbox" id="1" [checked]="ck" (change)="change()">`

and use `ngModel` to get value

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-checkbox',
  template: `<input type="checkbox" id="1" [(ngModel)]="ck" (change)="change()">`,
})
export class MyCheckbox implements OnChanges  {
  @Input()
  ck=true;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    console.log("2");
  }

  change(){
    console.log(this.ck);
  }

}
```

Comment: Ah, I understand the problem now. Thank you.